# SAP UI5 Dynamically switch between fragments

Tags: sapui5

How do I dynamically switch between two fragments using click / press event?

I have the following XML fragment which in turn has nested two fragments:

```
<core:FragmentDefinition
    xmlns="sap.m"
    xmlns:core="sap.ui.core">
  <IconTabFilter
      id="containerFrag"
      text="{name}"
      key="{id}">
    <dependents>
      <core:Fragment
          fragmentName="com.example.fragments.fragment1"
          type="XML" />
      <core:Fragment
          fragmentName="com.example.fragments.fragment2"
          type="XML" />
    </dependents>
  </IconTabFilter>
</core:FragmentDefinition>
```

Assuming each fragment has a button who's handler has the following

```
buttonPress: function(oEvent) {
  let oView = this.getView();
  let showFrag1 = oEvent.getParameter("arguments"); //showFrag1 = true / false
  let fragToShow = showFrag1 ? oView.byId("frag1Id").clone() : oView.byId("frag2Id").clone()
  let container = oView.byId("containerFrag");
  container.destroyContent();
  container.addContent(fragToShow);
}
```

When I debug using chrome, fragToShow updates with the correct frag depending on the showFrag1 argument, but the view doesn't get updated - container.addContent(fragToShow) seems to have no effect except if I reload the page

Comment: could you not parameterize the `fragmentName` property? (and bind it to a json model variable?)

Comment: maybe you want to hide and show fragment instead.

Comment: I'd agree with @D.Seah - Why not put both fragments in the content aggregation where you want them and just use the `setVisible` method to control which one is displayed (or even better, bind the `visible` property)? Then you aren't duplicating elements/controls, which is probably resulting in a memory leak.

Comment: Unfortunately, fragments do not have a `visible` property of any kind... seems like a massive oversight though

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why this works but I had to go one up from the container and insert the new fragment there like so:

```
let container = oView.byId("containerFrag");
container.getParent().destroyContent();
container.getParent().addContent(fragToShow);
```

This example also helped: https://ui5.sap.com/#/entity/sap.ui.layout.form.Form/sample/sap.ui.layout.sample.Form354 - though they use `removeAllContent` and `insertContent`, both seem to work just fine.

Thanks @D. Seah and @Ethan Jewett